# Do the white lights on the chimneys of the Tokyo area incineration plants serve an aviation purpose?

Tags: airport-lighting, japan

At least 新江東清掃工場 (Shinkoto Incineration Plant), 江戸川清掃工場 (Edogawa Incineration Plant) and 市川市 クリーンセンタ (Ichikawa Clean Center) ー blink with white lights in series.

I know that the red lights of other buildings and structures are for air traffic safety.

But these plants are relatively low. Their chimneys have the lights attached. And as said they blink white.

Yet the near port probably has no use for these lights.

I suspect this is for air traffic. Is this some sort of guidance system marking flight vectors or something?

Comment: I'm guessing that very few of us read Japanese, could you translate that part into English? Is it the name of some plants? Usually they have English equivalents.

Comment: Can you please state the relation to- and bearing from- the airport (which?) you have in mind? It will make it easier to check the right aeronautical chart.

Comment: it's HND (Haneda Tokyo)

Comment: Since you are writing your question in English, on an English language website, what is the purpose of embedding Japanese language characters?  Does this contribute anything to our understanding of the information you seek?

Comment: These are place names, you'll need them to find them in Google maps.